# Image keeps enlarging while orientation of the page changes

Tags: jquery, iphone, html

I'm facing a problem while developing a iphone mobile web application using jquery mobile 1.3.1,

I have a image which fits perfectly on the screen during load, but if there is a change in  orientation from portrait to landscape the images become enlarged

The first image shows the screen after the orientation has changed from landscape to portrait

The original Image

any suggestions on how the same can be rectified will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the image to be resize proportionally? If so, use this.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/AeXnV/2/

Remove width and height attributes in img tag.

```
<p id="myImage">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-YUUHSmN2iKc/URqH5KMr6OI/AAAAAAAABpE/ta3lwt2KDx8/s1600/desktop-wallpaper-1600x1200.jpg">
</p>
```

Add this css.

```
#myImage img{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks yeyene , your solution was perfect